# Upper bound on the minima of a function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Consider the function $f(x) = e^{-x} + \frac{x^n}{n!}$. This function has a single minima in $[0,\infty)$ for $n > 1$. Finding the minima in closed-form is difficult, but can an upper bound of the form $e^{-a n}$ be established for any $n > 1$? Intuitively, the minima should be exponentially small since this function is related to the truncation error of the Taylor series of $e^{-x}$.

Comment: "Minima" is the plural of "minimum". You are using it mostly in singular roles, it is slightly disorienting to see the plural.

Answer (score 1):

When you see an equation containing one exponential and polynomial terms, you must think about [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and its generalizations.

$$f(x) = e^{-x} + \frac{x^n}{n!} \qquad\implies \qquad f'(x)=- e^{-x}+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
$$f'(x)=0\qquad\implies \qquad x_{\text{min}}=(n-1)\, W\left(\frac{((n-1)!)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}}{n-1}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is the principal branch of Lambert function.

Now, have a look at function
$$g(x_{\text{min}})=\log\big( f(x_{\text{min}})\big)$$ as a function of $n$. You should have a nice surprise.

**Edit**

Consider
$$x_{\text{min}}=(n-1)\, W\left(\frac{((n-1)!)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}}{n-1}\right)$$ With $m=(n-1)$, consider
$$A=\frac{(m!)^{\frac{1}{m}}}{m}\implies \log(A)=\frac 1{m}\log(m!)-\log(m)$$ Using Stirling approximation
$$\log(A)=-1+\frac{\log (2 \pi m )}{2
   m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{\log (2\pi m)}{2 e m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$
$$W(A)=W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) (\log (2\pi m)}{2 m
   \left(W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)+1\right)}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$ All of that gives
$$x_{\text{min}}\sim n\,W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=x_*$$
$$f(x_*)=\frac{n^n W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n}{n!}+\left(e
   W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)^n$$

Using Stirling again
$$f(x_*) \sim  \left(1+\frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi  n } }\right)\left(e
   W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)^n$$

Comment: Thanks! It seems like $g(x_{\text{min}})$ is not a linear function of $n$, but I could bound it by $-W(1/e) n$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @krypt24. It is $g(n)$ which is linear